# Simple: Plot pairs of numbers

Tags: plotting

I'm a beginner. I've read a book about Mathematica and thought, I had learned a lot, but apparently…

I have a list with pairs of numbers like so, assigned to a variable "list":

```
   list = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 2}, {7, 6}}
```

**How can I plot this list**, when the first number of each pair is x, the second is y? It could look something like this:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `ListPlot`

Comment: Thanks. That was easy. My god.

Comment: To add to @Emad: look up the `Filling` option.

Comment: @J.M. Just did. Thank you!

Comment: How did you create the plot that you are showing?

Comment: @Szabolcs DiscretePlot[EulerPhi[x], {x, 1, 7}] -- but it seems, DiscretePlot doesn't work on lists.

Comment: `ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 2}, {7, 6}}, 
 Filling -> Axis]`

Comment: Thank you, Emad. I found that out, too, after your help. Is there a way to mark this question as solved?

Comment: @MarianStiehler you are welcome

Comment: @MarianStiehler I do not know but you can answer the question

Comment: I answered it, but can only accept my own answer in two days. Well… thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emad kareems solution worked just fine for me:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 2}, {7, 6}}, Filling -> Axis]
```